# CakePHP 3 : SQLSTATE[23000] database error

Tags: cakephp

Good morning,

I'm developing an CakePHP 3 application where the user logged in can post comments. After logged in, I've tried to post some comment and I got the following database error: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`aenterprises`.`comentario`, CONSTRAINT`comentario_ibfk_1`FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES`users`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)`

how can I solve this?

**users table**:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**comentario table**:

```
CREATE TABLE `comentario` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `autor` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `comentario` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `comentario`
--
ALTER TABLE `comentario`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--
ALTER TABLE `comentario`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `comentario_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**UsersTable.php - initialize function:**

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('users');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Comentario', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
    }
```

**ComentarioTable.php - initialize function**:

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('comentario');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: you only need to insert user_id in the comment table to whom the comments belogs to

Answer (score 0):

As per you database structure and defined constraint

```
ALTER TABLE `comentario`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `comentario_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

You need to remove this constraint first because this constraint restrict you on update query.

As per my experience no need to use UPDATE CASCADE. So use below constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE `comentario`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `comentario_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```